# notifyItemChanged(int) does not update RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm working on a messaging app.

The messages are displayed through `MessageAdapter.java`, which contains a `HashMap` from `ChatActivity.java` with the following attributes:

```
 Map messageTextBody = new HashMap();
        messageTextBody.put("number", howManyMessages);
        messageTextBody.put("message", messageText);
        messageTextBody.put("type", "text"); //text, audio, image, video etc
        messageTextBody.put("from", messageSenderID);
        messageTextBody.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
        messageTextBody.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
        messageTextBody.put("read", hasUserRead);
```

Which are sent to `Messages.java`:

```
public class Messages {
private String from, message, type, time, date;
private Boolean read;
private Integer number;

public Messages(){

}

public Messages(String from, String message, String type, String time, String date, Boolean read, Integer number) {
    this.from = from;
    this.message = message;
    this.type = type;
    this.time = time;
    this.date = date;
    this.read = read;
    this.number = number;

}


public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
}


public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}


public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}


public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}


public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}


public Boolean getRead() {
    return read;
}

public void setRead(Boolean read) {
    this.read = read;
}

public Integer getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(Integer number) {
    this.number = number;
}
}
```

And then accessed in `MessageAdapter.java`:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder>{
private List<Messages> userMessagesList;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference usersRef, messagesRef;
private Integer i;
private String messageSenderID;

public MessageAdapter (List<Messages> userMessagesList){
    this.userMessagesList = userMessagesList;
}

public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
   // public CircleImageView receiverProfileImage;
    public TextView nameReceived, senderMessageText, receiverMessageText, messageReceivedTime, messageSentTime, messageUnread;
    private String receivedTime, sentTime, lastReceivedTime, lastSentTime;
  //  private LoadingDots tinyDotsYou;


    public MessageViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView){
        super(itemView);

       // nameReceived = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.other_user_name);
        senderMessageText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_sent);
        receiverMessageText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_received);
        messageReceivedTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_received_time);
        messageSentTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_sent_time);
        messageUnread = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.unread_message_sent);

    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.custom_messages_layout, viewGroup, false);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    return new MessageViewHolder(view);

}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MessageViewHolder messageViewHolder, int i) {

if (fromMessageType.equals("text")){
            messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            messageViewHolder.messageUnread.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            messageViewHolder.messageReceivedTime.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            messageViewHolder.messageSentTime.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            //messageViewHolder.receiverProfileImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (fromUserID.equals(messageSenderID)){ //MESSAGE SENT

              //  messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                messageViewHolder.messageSentTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (!messages.getRead()){

                    messageViewHolder.messageUnread.setText(messages.getMessage());
                    messageViewHolder.messageUnread.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    messageViewHolder.messageUnread.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_bubble_3);
                    messageViewHolder.messageSentTime.setText(messages.getTime().substring(0,5));

                }

                else {
                    messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setText(messages.getMessage());
                    messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_bubble_2);
                    messageViewHolder.messageSentTime.setText(messages.getTime().substring(0,5));

                }


            }

            else  { //MESSAGE RECEIVED

                //messageViewHolder.tinyDotsYou.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                messageViewHolder.messageReceivedTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_bubble_1);
                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setText(messages.getMessage());
                messageViewHolder.messageReceivedTime.setText(messages.getTime().substring(0,5));

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  userMessagesList.size();
    }

}
```

Once the sender sends a new message, the structure

```
if (!messages.getRead()){

                    messageViewHolder.messageUnread.setText(messages.getMessage());
                    messageViewHolder.messageUnread.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    messageViewHolder.messageUnread.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_bubble_3);
                    messageViewHolder.messageSentTime.setText(messages.getTime().substring(0,5));

                }

                else {
                    messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setText(messages.getMessage());
                    messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_bubble_2);
                    messageViewHolder.messageSentTime.setText(messages.getTime().substring(0,5));

                }
```

checks whether the message was read or is still unread.

As for Database, I'm using Firebase database.

[image]

And a `ValueEventListener` from `ChatActivity.java` warns me when the state of "read" changes from "false" to "true".

```
RootRef.child("Messages").child(messageReceiverID).child(messageSenderID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            int i = 0;

                            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String uid = ds.getKey();

                                if (uid != null && isUserOnline.equals(true)){
                                    RootRef.child("Messages").child(messageReceiverID).child(messageSenderID).child(uid).child("read").setValue(true);
                                    RootRef.child("Messages").child(messageSenderID).child(messageReceiverID).child(uid).child("read").setValue(true);
                                    Map messageTextBody = new HashMap();
                                    messageTextBody.replace("read", true);
                                    messageAdapter.notifyItemChanged(i);

                                }
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
```

Notice that it also replaces the old value in Map messageTextBody and then calls for `notifyItemChanged()`.

If the user is online and the message is read, the chat bubble is displayed as "orange", meaning the message has been seen.

If the user hasn't read the message, the chat bubble is gray, [as the picture depicts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PhIB.jpg).

It's working when I leave and then return the ChatActivity, which forcefully updates the entire RecyclerView. But I can't get the single message that is updated from *unread* to *read* to be update in real time in the RecyclerView on the ChatActivity.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `Firebase UI` in this case `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is much easier to handle data changes on `Firebase Database` than creating your own `adapter`:
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Comment: I have been working on this in the past, I could accomplish it only with Frestore

Comment: @user2682025 seriously? Lemme ask you, then: is the migration to Firestore troublesome? I wrote a lot of code already and wouldn't bother leaving this aspect behind if it's not possible with Firebase RTDB.

Comment: @Yupi I will try it out, but everything else is working just fine and I really thought I could manage it in the current scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
RootRef.child("Messages").child(messageReceiverID).child(messageSenderID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange (@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){


        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String uid = ds.getKey();

            if (uid != null && isUserOnline.equals(true)) {
                RootRef.child("Messages").child(messageReceiverID).child(messageSenderID).child(uid).child("read").setValue(true);
                RootRef.child("Messages").child(messageSenderID).child(messageReceiverID).child(uid).child("read").setValue(true);
                Map messageTextBody = new HashMap();
                messageTextBody.replace("read", true);


            }

        }
       messageAdapter.notifyItemChanged(); // after end of loop using notifyItemChanged data
    }
}
```